# I am having Problem in JSON logging in JBOSS Wildfly

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, kie

I am trying to change the log format as JSON logging...
This is the Code...

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="JSON"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="JSON">
            <json-formatter date-format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" pretty-print="false" print-details="true" zone-id="UTC"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

But when I am trying to run it, I am getting error,

[Error Log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia6rm.png)

What might me the reason for this error, as I have seen that json-formatter is a valid tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Wildfly 10. Afaik json-formatter was introduced with [Wildfly 13](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/13.0/subsystem/logging/index.html)

Comment: Thank you @Laertes for the time being I have formatted my pattern formatter to json-type so that it can produce json output on the console.

Comment: BTW @Laertes , I am using Wildfly 14 version

Comment: But than, as @James R. Perkins wrote, a wrong schema version is used inside your standalone.xml. Thats maybe a leftover of a former migration...

Comment: Thank you @Laertes , Can you tell me how can I stop logging in the server.log? I basically removed all the places where i could find server.log, but still the file is being created. 
I removed this part, but it did not help  
`<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
<formatter>
<named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
</formatter>
<file relative-to ="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>`

Comment: As James told you, this should be sufficiant. But in general this is a separate question and you should open an new topic for it. If some of the anwers you got for you original question has solved your (original) problem, you should consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the schema version in your `standalone-full.xml` file. Generally speaking it's best to add the formatter with CLI.

```
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=JSON:add(date-format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", pretty-print=false, print-details=true, zone-id=UTC)
```

If you want to just edit the XML though you'd need to change the schema version to 6.0 which is the current version for WildFly 14.0.1.Final.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
```

Comment: thank you for your response @James R. Perkins . Can you tell me how can I stop logging in the server.log? I basically removed all the places where i could find server.log, but still the file is being created

Comment: I removed this part but did not help  
`<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>`

Comment: Did you stop the server first? Really all you need to do is remove the handler from the root logger; `/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)`.

Comment: `<root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
`
I have already removed File handler. But still it(server.log) is generated.
There is always a new kubernetes pod generated when I make changes and create some release.

Comment: The file will be created if you don't remove the file handler. You'd need to remove the handler too `/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:remove`.